# Draw points on click in webGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am a newbie, I am trying to draw a point of size 10, in WebGL, every time on MouseClick. At the point where I click. But Due to some logical error, it behaves a bit differently, it draws two points on click. Also I pass the colour black. It sometimes draws point of different colour(like green).

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script id="vertex" type="x-shader">
        attribute vec2 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec4 vColor;

        varying vec4 fColor;

        void main() {
            gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
            gl_PointSize = 10.0;
            fColor = vColor;


        }
    </script>
    <script id="fragment" type="x-shader">
        #ifdef GL_ES
            precision highp float;
        #endif
        varying vec4 fColor;
        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = fColor;

        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var points = [];
    var index = 0;
    function init1(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
            gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");   
            gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            var v = document.getElementById("vertex").firstChild.nodeValue;
            var f = document.getElementById("fragment").firstChild.nodeValue;

            var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(vs, v);
            gl.compileShader(vs);

            var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(fs, f);
            gl.compileShader(fs);

            var program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(program, vs);
            gl.attachShader(program, fs);
            gl.linkProgram(program);


            gl.useProgram(program);

            color= [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0];
            var vbuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);                                       
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 8*200, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            program.aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aVertexPosition");
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexPosition);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.aVertexPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


            var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 16*200, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            program.vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vColor);                 
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); 

            var flattenedVertices = [];
            var idx = 0;
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
                x=2*event.clientX/canvas.width-1;
                y=2*(canvas.height-event.clientY)/canvas.height-1;
                var pts = [x, y];
                points.push(pts);

                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);                                       
                gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 8*index++, new Float32Array(pts));
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);                                       
                gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 16*index++, new Float32Array(color));

        });
            render();   

    }

    function render(){
        gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, index);


        window.requestAnimationFrame(render);           

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init1()">
        <canvas id="mycanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
```

Above is my code, if anybody can help me fine tune it to work exactly what I want. There are a few problems I face,

1)I suspect that it draws two points on every click.
2)If I change the number 3 to 4 in line `gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);` 
  it only draws one point, the initial one and does not draws any point on successive clicks.
 Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incrementing `index` twice with 2 `index++` calls. Do it like this instead:

```
            var i = index;
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
            gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 8*i, new Float32Array(pts));
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
            gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 16*i, new Float32Array(color));
            index ++;
```

And I suspect you meant `gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);` rather than `gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);` Since your color is 4 elems: `var color= [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0];`

Also, use appropriate hint when allocating a new BufferData. If your data is not static (like how you are changing the buffer when "drawing" a new point) use `gl.STREAM_DRAW` or `gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW`. Using wrong hint can have a 5-10x performance loss.